# IIS browse web site list

Tags: windows

In Windows server 2008, how do I get list of browse web sites in IIS 7?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ### [To view a list of sites on a Web server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771280(v=ws.10).aspx)
>
> ### To Use the UI
>
> 1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see
>      Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to
>      locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> 2. In the **Connections** pane, click **Sites** in the tree.
> 3. View the list of sites or click a site in the list to modify site
>      properties from the **Actions** pane.
>
> ### Command Line
>
> To view a list of sites, type the following at the command prompt, and
>   then press ENTER:
>
> ```
> appcmd list site
> ```
>
> To view a list of sites on the Web server that have a specific
>   setting, you can filter the list results by including criteria on
>   which to filter the results of the command. To do this, use the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
> appcmd list site / attribute : value
> ```
>
> The variables attribute and value are the criteria on which you want
>   to filter the results. For example, you might have two sites that use
>   the same binding, which prevents them from running at the same time.
>   You can view a list of sites that use that binding by filtering the
>   results. To return a list of results filtered by sites that use the
>   HTTP protocol, and that listen for all IP addresses on port 80 without
>   a host header, type the following at the command prompt, and then
>   press ENTER:
>
> ```
> appcmd list site /bindings:http/*:80:
> ```
>
> For more information about Appcmd.exe, see [Appcmd.exe (IIS
>   7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771280(v=ws.10).aspx).
>
> ### WMI
>
> Use the following WMI classes, methods, or properties to perform this
>   procedure:
>
> - **ServerContainsSite** class
> - **Site** class
>
> For more information about WMI and IIS, see [Windows Management
>   Instrumentation (WMI) in IIS
>   7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771707(v=ws.10).aspx).
>   For more information about the classes, methods, or properties
>   associated with this procedure, see the [IIS WMI Provider
>   Reference](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=79310) on the MSDN
>   site.
>
> <sub>[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771280(v=ws.10).aspx)</sub>

Comment: Great, it's worked.